# Sending multiple arguments with "or" to a class?

Tags: python, django, forms

how are the instances of a class created if we send arguments to a class using "or".

views.py

```
form_ = SchoolForm(request.POST or NONE)
```

form.py

```
class SchoolForm(forms.Form):
    name =          forms.CharField()
    location =      forms.CharField(required=False)
```

Using  `form_ = SchoolForm(request.POST or NONE)`  instead of

```
form = SchoolForm()
if request.method == "POST":
    form = SchoolForm(request.POST)
```

Comment: In Python, `X or Y` _always_ produces `X` if `X` is truthy, and `Y` if `X` is falsey.

Comment: @ShreyamAdhikari you already got the answer about how `request.POST or None` works. Now : this idiom is actually an antipattern - if you get a POST request with no body, your form will be created without the `data` argument, which makes it an unbound form, and you will not get any error message.

Comment: but cant i use restrictions like <code> name = form.CharFiled(null=False, min_length=5, max_length=50)  </code> to take only valid datas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`or` is an operator that evaluates to exactly one of its operands. `SchoolForm` only sees one argument: the value of `request.POST` if it is "truthy" (i.e. `bool(request.POST)` evaluates to `True`), otherwise the value of `NONE`.

Based on your edit, I think what you want is

```
form_ = SchoolForm(request.POST if request.method == "POST" else None)
```

(assuming `SchoolForm(None)` and `SchoolForm()` are equivalent).

Comment: I'm correcting the misconception that `SchoolForm` is receiving multiple arguments. I don't know enough Django to know what argument (or arguments) would make sense to `SchoolForm`.

Comment: I am creating a form instance to send it as context in a template. But if I am getting a POST request i want to create it with the POST values.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `NONE` is not a valid keyword/object in Python and it would raise a parse error, unless you have defined a variable by the said name. I think you mean `None` instead.

Now, to answer your question, the boolean expression just returns the last value it had to parse, which in case of `or` is the first truthy value.

```
>>> 0 or 1
1
>>> 1 or 0
1
>>> 0 or False
False
>>> {} or None
None
```

Comment: `NONE` is a valid identifier, though; I think for the purposes of this question we can just assume that it is defined previously.

Comment: @chepner Why would you assume that he has explicitly defined a constant named `NONE` than that it's a typo?

Comment: Because the value hardly seems relevant to the question at hand. Your answer doesn't depend on any particular value assigned to `NONE`. If it's typo for `None`, that doesn't affect your answer either. I mean, `request` is just as undefined in the question as written; you're not calling that out.

Answer (score 0):

`or` operator will select the variable first if some value is found in it and other if the first variable is among `None`,`0`,`""` etc.

What I would also like to point out is, that these constructor parameters will be called by reference, so any changes made in the arguments even after declaration will impact the value of the args if directly used.

```
class Main:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x  = x

    @property
    def show(self):
        print self.x


b = {'first':'done'}
c = {} 

obj = Main(b or c)
obj.show

b['second'] = 'done'
# even after the class instantiate it will,
# still update the value of class variable. 
obj.show
```

> ```
> {'first': 'done'}
> {'second': 'done', 'first': 'done'}
> ```